# Why in Windows 'localhost' connection is reset while 127.0.0.1 and other specified in 'hosts' file work?

Tags: windows-xp, localhost, hosts

I want to test some HTTP server on localhost address under Windows (XP) and I get strange behaviour: when I enter http://localhost/ in my browser I get connection reset error, while putting http://127.0.0.1/ or anything other that is mapped to this address in the 'hosts' file works just fine and the start page is displayed.

I've closed some processes I suspected, disabled firewall, and it didn't help. For one moment the 'localhost' got back and then it's gone again without any reason. How can I track down what is meddling with localhost address under Windows?

Edit1:
Here is my 'hosts' file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       moin
```

The 'moin' entry works fine, 'localhost' is reset. The HTTP server is play! framework, and the way I must use it is 'http://localhost:9000/@tests'.

Edit2:
The ping response indicates that the 'localhost' resolves to IPv6 ::1 address:

```
C:\> ping localhost

Checking IZABELA [::1] using 32 bytes of data:

Response from ::1: time<1 ms
Response from ::1: time<1 ms
Response from ::1: time<1 ms
Response from ::1: time<1 ms
...
```

Comment: Could you post your hosts file? What HTTP server are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `localhost` passes your network adapter (note the `LMHOSTS` in it's advanced configuration, this does in essence turn processing of the HOSTS file on and off) and your network adapter could do something extra with it. If you visit `127.0.0.1` then it directly goes to the loopback adapter, as for the other entries your network adapter might just choose to forward them instead of handling them (like the `localhost` entry). You can get routing information using `route PRINT` in a command prompt:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.100    281 <--
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306 <==
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306 <==
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306 <==
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.100    281
    192.168.1.100  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.100    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.100    281
     192.168.11.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.11.1    276
     192.168.11.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.11.1    276
   192.168.11.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.11.1    276
     192.168.40.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.40.1    276
     192.168.40.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.40.1    276
   192.168.40.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.40.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.40.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.11.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.100    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.40.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.11.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.100    281
```

Note where I set the `<==` at the end, these ensure that the `127.0.0.1` interface is used when you visit a [loopback address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback).

Note where I set the `<--` at the end and `0.0.0.0` means any IP, these ensure that things like `localhost`, any other thing you forward in `HOSTS` and most IPs you visit are handled by your network adapter which uses the `192.168.1.100` interface and the `192.168.1.1` gateway.

A higher metric means more priority, so this is why `<==` has preference over `<--`.

More information can be found on [subnetworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) to understand the netmasks.

---

As for your problem:

- Check your IIS/Apache configuration.
- Disable your anti virus and firewall.
- Reset your network adapter to see if it solves the problem.
- Use the `Troubleshoot Problems` option to see if it resolves something.
- Use `ipconfig /flushdns` to clear DNS resolution.
- See what you get for `ping localhost`.
- Try to disable IPv6.
- Update the drivers for your network adapter.

Report back if you still have the problem, you might want to capture a [Wireshark trace](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: The firewall was disabled, as I stated before. I've added ping response to my question. Resetting adapter didn't help. Flushing DNS also didn't help. Updating drivers is impossible. More ideas?

Comment: @Rajish: Hmm, IPv6, does the same problem occur when you **disable IPv6** and thus only use IPv4? As **`localhost` resolves to the IPv6 variant** your server is most likely not listening to the IPv6 IP and thus `localhost` would not work. Updating your network drivers should be possible, why is it impossible?

Comment: I have already the 'newest' drivers for my hardware. **Disabling IPv6 at all did the trick.** Before that I've tried the trick described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/36f57ccf-7a76-4843-84bd-7bb945aad23f/) but it didn't work.